# internal enum is ruining my code

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

When I uncomment the internal enums, the panel local variable turns into an error.

I've been debugging this for a few hours already and I gave up. This is weird since this is exactly what the Microsoft Band Documentation told me to do.

What am I doing wrong ?

This is my code:

```
// create a new Guid for the tile
        Guid tileGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

        // create a new tile with a new Guid
        BandTile tile = new BandTile(tileGuid)
        {
            // enable badging (the count of unread messages)
            IsBadgingEnabled = true,
            // set the name
            Name = "Maps",
            // set the icons
            SmallIcon = smallIcon,
            TileIcon = tileIcon
        };

        // create a scrollable vertical panel that will hold 2 text messages
        ScrollFlowPanel panel = new ScrollFlowPanel
        {
            Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            Orientation = FlowPanelOrientation.Vertical,
            ColorSource = ElementColorSource.BandBase
        };

        // Define symbolic constants for indices to each layout that
        // the tile  has. The index of the first layout is 0. Since at
        // most 5 layouts are allowed, the max index value is 4.
        //        internal enum TileLayoutIndex
        //{
        //    MessagesLayout = 0
        //}

        // Define symbolic constants to uniquely (in MessagesLayout)
        // identify each of the elements of our layout
        // that contain content that the app will set
        // (that is, these Ids will be used when calling APIs
        // to set the page content)
    //            internal enum TileMessagesLayoutElementId : short
    //{
    //    Message1 = 1, // Id for the 1st message text block
    //    Message2 = 2, // Id for the 2nd message text block
    //}


    // add the text block to contain the first message
    panel.Elements.Add(
            new WrappedTextBlock
            {
                ElementId = (short)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message1,
                Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            // left, top, right, bottom margins
            Margins = new Margins(15, 0, 15, 0),
                Color = new BandColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
                Font = WrappedTextBlockFont.Small
            }

            );

// add the text block to contain the second message
        panel.Elements.Add(
        new WrappedTextBlock
        {
            ElementId = (short)TileMessagesLayoutElementId.Message2,
            Rect = new PageRect(0, 0, 245, 102),
            // left, top, right, bottom margins
            Margins = new Margins(15, 0, 15, 0),
            Color = new BandColor(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
            Font = WrappedTextBlockFont.Small
        }

        );

        // create the page layout
        PageLayout layout = new PageLayout(panel);

        try
        {
            // add the layout to the tile
            tile.PageLayouts.Add(layout);
        }
        catch (BandException ex)
        {
            // handle an error adding the layout
        }

        // Prerequisite: bandClient has successfully connected to a Band

        using (IBandClient bandClient = await
        BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))

            try
        {
            // add the tile to the Band
            if (await bandClient.TileManager.AddTileAsync(tile))
            {
                // tile was successfully added,
                // can proceed to set tile content with SetPagesAsync
            }
            else
            {
                // tile failed to be added, handle error
            }
        }
        catch (BandException ex)
        {
            // handle a Band connection exception
        }
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await
        BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
        using (IBandClient bandClient = await
        BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))

            try
            {
                // get the current set of tiles
                IEnumerable<BandTile> tiles = await
            bandClient.TileManager.GetTilesAsync();

                foreach (var t in tiles)
                {
                    // remove the tile from the Band
                    if (await bandClient.TileManager.RemoveTileAsync(t))
                    {
                        // do work if the tile was successfully removed
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (BandException ex)
            {
                // handle a Band connection exception
            }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot declare an enum within a method. Move the enum outside the method.

Comment: Where outside the method? The Button Method?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to type the internal enum outside the private method. Thank you @Michael Liu.